# customizing linkify method in java(Android Studio)

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, linkify

I have in my layout, a `TextView`, the id is `textView1`. In my java class I have
this piece of code:

```
TextView link1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tJabalEnlace1);
link1.setText("https://stackoverflow.com/");
Linkify.addLinks(link1, Linkify.ALL);
```

What this does is, initialize the `textView`, set the text of it, and linkifies it. It works just fine, but what I would like to do is, make the textView be "Link" and the direction to be the link in the code, but I don't know how.

UPDATE:
I wanted to do it with linkify, I found another way of doing it:
-Set the text View Clickable in the layout file.
-Java:

```
TextView link1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tJabalEnlace1);
                link1.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
                link1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(intent);}});
}
```